# Chrome behaviour after accepting untrusted certificate

Tags: google-chrome, behaviorsubject, self-signed-certificate

I currently meet some issue with Chrome behaviour.

My company is using self certificate product on the internal network where are hosted our applications.

My users are following the current steps:

1. Going on the website, accept the "untrusted certificate"
2. Using the app X time
3. Clicking on one button making an Ajax Call to get images on the Apache server
4. Ajax calls are resulting in a 404 failed request
   [image]

I figured out that I can reproduce this behaviour by "Re-enabling" the warning before to click on the button making the Ajax Call:

[image]

There is my questions:

1. Is it possible that chrome is "Re-enabling" the warning automatically after X times ? If yes how many time ? And where can I find more informations about this subject ?
2. Is there an option to disable Chrome to "Re-enable" the warning by itself ? If yes how ?

Thank you.